# sources.list error in r installation - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04

I followed the instructions given in 
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README
using the mirror  http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/

The sources.list file now looks like :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://sa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

deb  http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

Upon running sudo apt-get update I get several err messages one of which I believe is relevant :

```
Err http://ftp.iitm.ac.in trusty/ Packages
```

There is something wrong with the sources.list file which isn't allowing all the archives to be recovered. I'm a newbie to ubuntu. What do I do?

Comment: Hi, you did not select a cran mirron, it is the url of the help page. Please go to this page [link](http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) and replace **http://ftp.iitm.ac.in** with a correct cran mirror, like **http://cran.rstudio.com/**. It is better if you chose the closer mirror to your location.

Comment: deb    http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
I appended this in sources.list and have used cran.rstudio now and I  still have the same error. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean? By the way, the ftp.iitm.ac.in is the mirror closest to me (India)

Comment: no, the name of the mirror link must be complete (example  `deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` ), take a look at the link I posted in the precedent message to choose one.

Comment: deb  http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
I've already added this complete version (you can see the last line of the sources.list file I gave above). And I obtained the link from the list of mirrors. where <  htp://ftp.iiitm.ac.in.cran/    > was the link listed for India.